# Dialogflow get and send intents list

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

There is a method that returns the list of all intents in the specified agent: [projects.agent.intents.list](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/list)

But I dont understand where to use this, and how to send this list to user. So basically what I want: user send to bot message: "list of intents" and bot send him back list of existing intents. Please, guide me what and where to code? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `projects.agent.intents.list` it will return a JSON file of the following representation:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      object (Intent)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

If you want to access intents and send it to the user you should parse the JSON file and access each individual intent and send it and the manner you want (you can populate them to a list or send each of them as separate text message).

Comment: thank you. I understand this in general. I dont know where exactly to code this on Dialogflow site. What I mean is: I have intent named "List_of_intents". To this intent i added training phrase "list of intents". The next field – text response. What i have to write to this field? Please help me with a complete code, if possible. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @VladimirSidorenkov you can code it in Fulfillments. On your intent page enable Fulfillments and using the left menu you can navigate to fulfillment page.